# Time Signature Meta Message in MIDI

Tags: midi

I am working on a MIDI project using mido library in Python. I see in the manual a meta message for time signature with value: notated_32nd_notes_per_beat which has a default value of 8.

```
<meta message time_signature numerator=4 denominator=4 clocks_per_click=24 notated_32nd_notes_per_beat=8 time=0>
```

Which makes sense. However, can I define it like:

```
<meta message time_signature numerator=4 denominator=4 clocks_per_click=24 notated_32nd_notes_per_beat=32 time=0>
```

Does this increase the display resolution when shown in a score/typesetting software? What is the usage of this please?

[time_signature (0x58) meta message in midi files](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta_message_types.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file header specifies the number of ticks per beat, and the tempo messages specify the length of a beat, in microseconds. These value are needed to correctly play back the file.

The last field of the time signature message specifies how the tick values in the MIDI file relates to notes in a score. It does not affect at what time events are sent (so a pure playback program will ignore this message), but how notes are displayed.

For example, if the header says there are 100 ticks per beat, and the time signature has the default of 8 32<sup>th</sup> notes per beat, then a note-on/note-off pair with a distance of 100 ticks is displayed as a quarter note. If you change the time signature to 32 32<sup>th</sup> notes per beat, then a length of 100 ticks corresponds to a whole note.

Comment: Thank you very much, CL again. This is confusing, but your explanation made it understandable. ُMy guess was right then, this effect the note display. But What is the use case of this?

Comment: It's useful if you want to have something other than a quarter note as a beat.

Comment: So, since it is not explicitly provided, how can we calculate the `ticks_per_beat` given `clocks_per_click` and `32th notes per beat`?

Comment: @cenestpamoi The metronome is not directly related to that. And how to choose the length of a tick depends on the tempo and the desired timing precision. Ask a new question.

Comment: Οκ thanks a lot! but when reading a midi file, is n t the time-precision already predefined? Or is it like setting the sampling_rate for example when reading an audio file? Because in my case in particular, there is no ticks_per_beat included within meta messages

Comment: @cenestpamoi `ticks_per_beat` is part of the file header.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain further? What exactly is the `file header` so that someone could actually  obtain the value of `ticks_per_beat`?

Comment: @cenestpamoi To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.